# "Login" activity: ProgressDialog alternative

Tags: android

I have got an activity where the user can enter host name, user name and password and then click on a "Verify credentials" button. Then the credentials will be checked, which will take some time. In the meantime the user should neither be able to change the credentials nor to click on "Verify" again. So, a modal dialog like the *ProgressDialog* seems perfect for this.

Unfortunately, ProgressDialog has the well-know limitations regarding orientation changes etc. The guide ([UI/Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)) tells to avoid ProgressDialog at all and use a ProgressBar in the layout instead (like in [Progress & Activity](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html)). What does this mean? Shall I create another activity with just one progress bar? Or disable all input fields and put a progress bar on top of it? Sounds quite weird to me... whats your preferred solution?

Comment: Just a small advice in case you didn't know, if your layout is not too complicated, you can use `setContentView` as many times as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Best thing which I use is:

Put a `ProgressBar` just beside the Login `Button`.

I have put a progressbar beside it(Whose visibility is set to `View.GONE`) in the `OnCreate` method.

When the user clicks on the Login/Submit button, I set the visibility of the button to `View.GONE` and visibility of `ProgressBar` to `View.VISIBLE`.

It looks good and the user cannot click on the button until the work is done, If an error occurs, toggle the visibility to let the user try again

Comment: Your answer is nice, but when the orientation will be changed, all the components will be in their initial states.

Comment: onResume will be called before the onCreate for the first time and at that time all the initializations that are done in onCreate will be null. So it will generate a NPE (Null pointer Exception)

Comment: Set a flag variable (`boolean`) to true whenever the user clicks on Login `Button`. In the `OnResume` method, check if the variable is `true`. If true, show the `ProgressBar` and Hide the `Button`. This will work :) @SalmanKhakwani

Comment: That will definitely work my friend. But it is a bad practice.

Comment: It isn't a bad practice. Not at all. Safe and simple.

Comment: It is, my friend. What if the user has already used the Login Button and then using the Login Activity for the second time and changes the orientation before clicking the Login button ?
The login button will disappear and the Progress bar will show up.

Comment: Umm, may i know the reason for down-voting my answer ?

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani: In which world (case) will `onResume` be called **before** `onCreate`? I fear you are not very familiar with the Android `Activity` lifetime cycle. Read more on the Activity life cylcle at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I agree with you here, but when i was dealing with orientation changes in my App my logs on `onResume()` method were being printed in the first place.

Comment: Choosing a best answer is never a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

Like @micro.pravi mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18300611/455493), you can implement the `ProgressBar` inside your layout. To keep the state after an orientation change you have to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to save and restore important values, i.e. private variables, like the `private boolean isChecking`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public boolean isProcessing;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle stateBundle) {
        super.onCreate(stateBundle);
        // Set Layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(stateBundle!=null) {
            // read your data here from the bundle
            isProcessing =  stateBundle.getBoolean("isProcessing");
        }

        setUiState(isChecking);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle stateBundle) {
        // Second value of getBoolean is the default value
        isProcessing =  stateBundle.getBoolean("isProcessing", false);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(stateBundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle stateBundle) {
        // Save the critical data
        stateBundle.putString("isProcessing", isProcessing);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(stateBundle);
    }
    @Override 
    protected onResume() {
        setUiState(isProcessing);
    }
    private setUiState(boolean processing) {
        textView.setEnabled(!processing);
        button.setEnabled(!processing);
        progressbar.setVisibility(processing?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This should be used to saved any critical data on orientation change or when the App is being killed and later restored by the OS. You don't have to save your `TextView` data, as the defautl View elements already handle this by themselves. Also do not store Image data this way. Instead store the Uri or path to the Url and load it on restore

Answer (score -1):

For temporarily solving your problem, you can continue using the `Progress Dialog` and put this line in your `Login Activity's` tag in  `Manifest.xml` file :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Using this line of code will not affect the `Progress Dialog` on orientation changes. But it is considered a wrong practice according to Android Development's Documentation.

In the long run, i recommend you to Preserve the states for orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks, I have already found the ways how to use ProgressDialog nevertheless. But I wonder how the *intended* Android 4+ way of showing a progress while disabling user input?

Comment: You should just restore and preserve the states for handling orientation changes and using the Progress Dialog is just fine way of letting the user know that the activity is doing some important processing :]

Comment: May i know the reason for down-voting my answer ?